# Use MD5 or random for file naming?

Tags: random, upload, md5

Which method for file naming is better?

Method 1:

- MD5 a string/file (whatever), we get the result using [0-9a-z] characters with 32 string length
- (10+26)^32 combinations

Method 2 [as outlined here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#87487):

- Use PHP to random generate a set of characters [0-9a-zA-Z] characters with 32 string length
- (10+26+26)^32 combinations

Obviously method 2 has more combinations and randomness, but why don't people use method 2 but use method 1?

Comment: Because some silly file systems don't have case-sensitive file names, and because the MD5 hash has more meaning than just being random, i.e. can serve as a fingerprint/checksum of the file.

Comment: what situation do we need to check sum of the upload file?

Comment: It allows you to verify that the contents have not been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two reasons:

1. Some file systems (e.g. VFAT, FAT32) don't support case-sensitive file names.
2. The MD5 hash has value beyond being random, i.e. it can serve to fingerprint/checksum the file. This can help you:

   - verify that the content of the file has not changed since it was created;
   - prevent storing duplicated content.

Comment: i doubt the use for prevent storing duplicated content; i.e if 2 users upload the same image, and one of the user want to delete the image on server, so would I delete the share image?

Comment: @SacbmcpdSamuel That argument doesn't hold water. It would be trivial to check whether the image is still being referenced by another user before deciding to delete it. It's the same as asking if everyone has finished eating before clearing the table.

Comment: @SacbmcpdSamuel Even better would be to just delete the reference and then run a scheduled (daily, weekly, whatever) cleanup job to delete files that are no longer being referenced.

Comment: the user will wonder why product have been deleted and the image src still there? instead of md5 i think unique string is suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

3 reasons.

- Not many people realized the rand() gives more randomness
- md5 works in most cases. Historically, it has been used as a unique identifier for things so people like to use it since its very common
- As @Robby pointed out, some operating systems like windows don't support case sensitive file names.
  `aaAAaa.txt` and `aaaaaa.txt` are two different things on a unix system but the samething on a windows system